# How to require class to file PHP?

Tags: php

I write tests in php. I have a problem. In `registrationTest.php` I write tests.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../fixture/page.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../fixture/assert.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../fake/TestSession.php';
require "test/fake/TestHeaders.php";
require "test/fake/TestHeader.php";

$html = openPageParameters('login.php', [
    'login'    => 'Tom',
    'password' => 'aaaaaa',
    'signIn'   => 1
]);

$content = $html->elements("//span[@class='error']");
assertArrayEquals([], $content);
```

In `page.php` I have a 3 function.

```
<?php

require 'HtmlContent.php';

function renderedPage(string $entryPoint): string
{
    \ob_start();
    require $entryPoint;
    return \ob_get_clean();
}

function openPageParameters(string $entryPoint, array $post): HtmlContent
{
    $_POST = $post;
    return new HtmlContent(renderedPage($entryPoint));
}

function openPage(string $entryPoint): HtmlContent
{
    return new HtmlContent(renderedPage($entryPoint));
}
```

And I have HtmlContent in `HtmlContent.php`

```
class HtmlContent
{
    private DOMXpath $xPath;

    public function __construct(string $html)
    {
        $this->xPath = new \DOMXpath($this->document($html));
    }

    private function document(string $html): DomDocument
    {
        $document = new \DomDocument();
        @$document->loadHTML($html);
        return $document;
    }

    public function elements(string $xPath): array
    {
        $results = [];
        foreach ($this->query($xPath) as $element) {
            foreach ($element->childNodes as $node) {
                $results[] = $node->nodeValue;
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }

private function query(string $xPath): mixed
{
    $elements = $this->xPath->query($xPath);
    if ($elements === false) {
        throw new Exception("Malformed xPath selector: '$xPath'");
    }
    return $elements;
}

}
```

This is `TestHeader.php`

```
class TestHeader
{
    public function send(): void
    {
    }
}
```

This is `TestHeaders.php`

```
class TestHeaders
{
    public function profile(int $userId): TestHeader
    {
        return new TestHeader();
    }
}
```

I require `TestHeaders.php` to file `registrationTest.php`. When I run test show error `Class TestHeader not found in TestHeaders.php` So I require `TestHeader.php` to `registrationTest.php` and now show me error

> `Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty in C:\PhpstormProject\messbox\test\fixture\HtmlContent.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\PhpstormProject\messbox\test\fixture\HtmlContent.php(15): DOMDocument->loadHTML('') #1 C:\PhpstormProject\messbox\test\fixture\HtmlContent.php(9): HtmlContent->document('') #2 C:\PhpstormProject\messbox\test\fixture\page.php(15): HtmlContent->__construct('') #3 C:\PhpstormProject\messbox\test\test\registrationTest.php(582): openPageParameters('login.php', Array) #4 {main}   thrown in C:\PhpstormProject\messbox\test\fixture\HtmlContent.php on line 15`

I don't understand why this problem is. Someone could what I do wrong and how I do fix this problem ?

Comment: you are passing empty string ($html variable) to loadHTML function

Comment: @Giacomo M I know that I pass empty string to $html variable, but I don't know why this variable is empty. I pass $ntryPoint variable which has `login.php` so this $html should not be empty

Comment: check login.php file

Comment: Seems like you need to debug `renderedPage` and see what's going on there. Maybe the paths are not what you expect? Try removing the buffer and DOM stuff, and just running `var_dump(require $entryPoint)` in that function to see what's in there

Comment: @ChrisHaas The error not show if I do `var_dump(require $ntryPoint)`  I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Because we're debugging, let's simplify things for now. Change your page.php to this and only this: https://3v4l.org/LuR6V. Then post the contents of the var_dump. My guess is it is an empty string. Does login.php echo anything or just return?

Comment: @ChrisHaas  var_dump show `int(1)`

Comment: This is telling me that `require 'login.php'` isn't doing what you think it is doing. What does that code do?

Comment: @ChrisHaas `require 'login.php` should login.php but `int(1), I don't konw why this  is happening, should be `require login.php`

Comment: “require 'login.php should login.php” - I’m not sure what that means. Requiring/including code effectively copies and pastes the code from that file into the place that includes it, then executed it. I’m seeing you are mocking POST parameters, does your login check other parameters that might not be sent? And once again, what are you literally echoing on login.php?.